# Flex box item with horizontal scroll does not fit the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box container which has two child elements, left side and right side.
The right side item should have an horizontal scrollbar and to fit the content.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.left-side {
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-side {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.right-side > div {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.right-side > p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.notes {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    left side
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div>
      right side
    </div>
    <p>
      Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
      Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
      Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can we reach it by using flexbox or any work around.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wu7hke?file=index.js,index.html,style.css)

Comment: You mean `.right-side > p { overflow-x: auto; }`?

Comment: @InSync no, the right side item should have the scroll bar as it is demonstrated. should use the available space to fit the content

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say "fill content" not "fit content" re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content  `flex-basis: fit-content;

/* Automatically size based on the flex item's content */
flex-basis: content;`

Comment: Question: why do you want a scrollbar?  Why not a modern responsive layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here I create blocks to act as containers.

- Parent => Left : Right

Super ugly content in those three container concepts

- This has some super ugly background colors and borders just to show what is where.
- Set body to use a standard default for most browsers 16px font and no margins or padding
- Gave the parent-container grid layout with a left and right column; Left has a min/max size and right is whatever it contains
- Grid gap on the parent container just to show left/right separation
- Left side set some elements and aligned them just to show you can have a great deal of control within the container
- Set right side to align to the top of the flow/block and have a scroll bar as asked in the OP question
- Added various element on right with ugly backgrounds just to show we can control within the container but also contain within the container due to the scroll setting
- The rest is just super ugly CSS to show what is where and is way overblown as a result

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(6.25rem, 25%) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.left-side {
  align-self: start;
  background-color: #FF000011;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid #FF000088;
  display: grid;
}

.right-side {
  background-color: #90EE90;
  align-self: start;
  /* change "auto" to "scroll" to force an always visible horizontal scroll color only wors in firefox as of this posting date */
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.right-side>.right-header {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-side>.right-content {
  background-color: #FF80FF;
  display: grid;
}

.right-side .right-text {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.next-child-right {
  /* just to show we can style content independent of layout */
  justify-self: safe center;
  align-self: baseline;
  border: outset 1px #00FF00AA;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.block-thing {
  /* push me to right of block (flow end) and put on bottom/end */
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: end;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 8ch;
  border: double #00FF00;
}

.blocky-child-right {
  width: 50rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  text-align: end;
}

.block-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="block-header">left side</div>
    <div>Next left</div>
    <div class="block-thing">block thing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="right-header block-header">
      right side
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <p class="right-text">
        Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
        Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
        Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph
      </p>
      <div class="next-child-right">I am the next content</div>
      <div class="blocky-child-right">blocky I am</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all the right side children elements should be filling the right side container, if you scroll you will see that the paragraph is longer then others. they expected to have auto width to fill the container if it gets wider.

Comment: That is style you can set on those;  Your question should be edited to add that as a clear requirement since many elements do have different style as I show here and the single one in the question does not clearly demonstrate the lack of that occurring nor call out that specific requirement..